# FromRequest Validation for Get Method is not working -Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, validation, laravel-formrequest

I am doing GET request validation using a `FormRequest` class.
The rules seem correct, but validation is not working.

My `FormRequest` class looks like this:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Requests;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;

class ShowTheSubjectRequest extends FormRequest
{
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    public function rules()
    {        
        return [
            'subject_code' => 'required|exists:the_subjects,sub_x',
        ];
    }

    public function messages()
    {
        return [
            'subject_code.required' => 'Required,Can\'t Be Empty',
            'subject_code.exists' => 'Entry does\'t exist with us.Choose Correct'
        ];
    }
{
```

I always get the following response:

```json
{
    "message": "The given data was invalid.",
    "errors": {
        "subject_code": [
            "Required,Can't Be Empty"
        ]
    }
}
```

I read somewhere that `FormRequest` is not good for GET method. How else can I validate for GET requests?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use form validation on GET request because it validates the request body, and GET requests have no body.
To validate the query string (the URL part after `?`), you need to use a middleware which would abort the request whenever something goes wrong.

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class ValidateSubjectCode
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        $subjectCode = $request->route()->param('subject_code');

        //Your validation logic

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

Because this validation is probably specific to a controller, you could also define a Closure middleware into your controller `__construct`

```php
public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware(function ($request, $next) {
            $subjectCode = $request->route()->param('subject_code');

            //Your validation logic

            return $next($request);
    }
```

Comment: This is my Route
Route::get('show/{subject_code}', 'V1\Admin\Create\SubToTop\TheSubjectController@show')->name('show.subject');
Can you elaborate about that middleware

Comment: Earlier I am using a separate action class to handle validation and injecting them  in the controller and using if($validator->fails()) .Is that method okay or i should stick to FormRequest Method.

Comment: your answer worked for me but I want know about this'approch 
public function all($keys = null)
{
   // Add route parameters to validation data
   return array_merge(parent::all(), $this->route()->parameters());
}

Answer (score 1):

To define simple regex validation rules on route parameters, you can use the `where()` method at the end of your route definition in `web.php` like this

```php
Route::get('show/{subject_code}', [SubjectController::class, 'show'])
    ->name('subject.show')
    ->where(['subject_code' => '[0-9]+'])
```

Answer (score 0):

An easy option is to just take the values you want to validate and [merge](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/collections#method-merge) them into the request body. Simply add a [`prepareForValidation()` method](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/validation#preparing-input-for-validation) to the `FormRequest` class that does this.

The question doesn't say if the value is a route parameter (e.g. `https://example.com/api/v1/subject_code_goes_here/foo`) or a query string item (e.g. `https://example.com/api/v1/foo?subject_code=xxx`.)

In the case of route parameter it would look like this:

```php
public function prepareForValidation(): void
{
    $this->merge([
        "subject_code" => $this->route()->parameter("subject_code");
    ]);
}
```

A query string item would look like this:

```php
public function prepareForValidation(): void
{
    $this->merge([
        "subject_code" => $this->query()->get("subject_code");
    ]);
}
```